# How do I get the properties which are available on some UIAutomationElement?

Tags: c++, windows, ui-automation

I'm using the [Microsoft UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx) framework to build a program which can view the properties of some UI objects (for debugging purposes). It's mostly smooth sailing, except for the fact that I cannot find out how to enumerate the available properties on some [`IUIAutomationElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671425(v=vs.85).aspx).

I saw that (all?) possible [Property Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671212(v=vs.85).aspx) are documented, and that one can get use [IUIAutomation::GetProgrammaticPropertyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671543(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the name of a property given it's property identifier. Furthermore, [IUIAutomationElement::GetCurrentPropertyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee696040(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used to get the value of a property given its ID.

What's missing though is a list of all valid property identifiers (at runtime) given some object. Does anybody know how to do that? I'd like to avoid hardcoding a list of properties to check.

Comment: Not sure what you would exactly need that, but you can use PollForPotentialSupportedProperties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671550.aspx, otherwise you can check UIVerify source code and see if they do something magic: https://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for your comment! I'll have a try with `PollForPotentialSupportedProperties`, it sounds like what I need.